# I want one character to escape IsLetterOrDigit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following function that checks a string and keeps only the letters and digits. All other characters are removed.

However I want one character only "-" to escape this function and not to be removed. For instance I want Jean-Paul to stay as it with the "-" in between the two names. How can I do that?

```
String NameTextboxString = NameTextbox.Text;
NameTextboxString = new string((from c in NameTextboxString
                                where char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) 
                                select c).ToArray);
nameLabel.Text = NameTextboxString;
```

Comment: `where char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '-'` ?

Comment: Note that method syntax would be a better choice here: `NameTextboxString .Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try:

```
where char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '-'
```

Hoping that the user will not input string like `--lolol-i-am-an-hackerz--`

---

To simplify a bit your code:

```
nameLabel.Text = new string(NameTextbox.Text.Where((c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '-')).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks.... I'm actually sanitizing the string after this function to prevent any unwanted strings

Comment: You can't cast a `WhereEnumerableIterator` to a `string`. This will throw at run-time.

Comment: @Thomas In-order to convert a `char[]` to a `string`, you'll need to use the constructor as the OP did in the question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov so `new string(NameTextbox.Text.Where((c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '-')))` should be good?

Comment: Should be `new string(NameTextbox.Text.Where((c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '-')).ToArray())`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

A little extension method can also come in handy:

```
public static class CharExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLetterDigitOrSpecialChar(this char c, 
              params char[] specialCharacters)
    {
        return char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || specialCharacters.Any(x => c.Equals(x));
    }
}
```

And then consume it like this:

```
NameTextboxString = new string(
        NameTextboxString.Where(x => x.IsLetterDigitOrSpecialChar(('-'))).ToArray());
```

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it's [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an or condition to your `where` clause:

```
from c in name where char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c=='-' select c
```

see below the complete Fiddle:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var name = ""Jean-Paul@@~()"";
        var cleaned_name= new string((from c in name where char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c=='-' select c).ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(cleaned_name);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Jean-Paul
```